# Prove that the loxodrome crosses all meridians at a constant angle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, spherical-geometry, geodesy

How to prove that the [loxodrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line) (the rhumb line) crosses all meridians at a **constant** angle?

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\psi}{2}\right) = e^{k\phi}, \quad k = \text{constant}$$

where  $\psi$ is the latitude of a point on a sphere, and $\phi$ is the longitude.

[image]

Comment: what is the formula for a "meridian"

Comment: I don't know and task condition mentions **all** meridians.

Comment: A meridian is a line of latitude (so, in your notation, $\psi$ constant).

Comment: @TedShifrin: [A meridian is a line of longitude.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(geography))

Comment: LOL ... I never use this word because it's always so confusing. Note that dictionary.com says "a circle of constant longitude passing through a given place on the earth's surface and the terrestrial poles." This is wrong, too. Constant longitude would mean a line of latitude. Ugh.

Comment: Please, help me to solve this task in the context of multivariable calculus or hint on how to approach it.

Comment: Find the angle between tangent vectors to the two curves, @OlehBerehovskyi

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo I checked it before and, trust me, there is no such question(

Comment: @TedShifrin: Heh. It's sort of like lines parallel to the $y$-axis are given by $x=a$, I've always hated that. But, one way I remember this is that longitude lines are long.

Comment: @LeeMosher: I have no problem with latitude and longitude. In my differential geometry notes, I prefer to refer to parallels and profile curves of surfaces of revolution :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stereographic projection $\sigma:\>\dot S^2\to{\mathbb R}^2$ maps the point $P\in \dot S^2$with geographical cordinates $[\psi,\phi]$ to the point $\sigma(P)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ with polar coordinates $[r,\phi]$, whereby $r$ is given by
$$r={\cos\psi\over 1-\sin\psi}\ .$$
This is easily verified in a figure  showing a half meridian circle of $S^2$. Writing $\tan{\psi\over2}=:t$ we therefore have
$$r={{1-t^2\over 1+t^2}\over 1-{2t\over1+t^2}}={1+t\over1-t}=\tan\left({\pi\over4}+{\psi\over2}\right)\qquad\bigl(=e^{k\phi}\bigr)\ .$$
This shows that the stereographic image $\sigma(\ell)$ of your loxodrome is a logarithmic spiral $r=e^{k\phi}$ in the plane. Such a spiral intersects all radii originating at $(0,0)$ under the same angle $\alpha$ (which depends on $k$). Now these radii are just the stereographic images of the meridians on $S^2$. Since $\sigma$ is known to be conformal it follows that $\ell$ intersects all meridians on $S^2$ under the same angle $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you so much